# Event on route change in app.comnonent.ts

Tags: javascript, angular

I have problem about recognizing routing. I want to change panel bar position after route will be changed. Panel bar is in app.component user can change page with it. What should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26jDx.png)

[image]

---

I tried something like this in constructor but problem is that constructor executes only once a time in app.component.

```
this.curRouter = window.location.href;
if(this.curRouter.includes('test')) {
    this.routerResult='test'; 
} else if(this.curRouter.includes('shipping')) { 
    this.routerResult='shipping'; 
} else if(this.curRouter.includes('new')) {
    this.routerResult='new';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes but I failed.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: `this.curRouter = window.location.href;
    
    if(this.curRouter.includes('test')) {
      this.routerResult='test';
    }
    else if(this.curRouter.includes('shipping')) {
      this.routerResult='shipping';
    }
    else if(this.curRouter.includes('new')) {
      this.routerResult='new';
    }`  I tried something like this in constructor but problem is that constructor executes only once a time in app.component.

Comment: Need to provide more information than this

Comment: Hi mate, please include your full constructor code, a first thing, you don't want to use window.location when you should be injecting angular Router

Comment: Where are your app-routing.module?? Why you are trying to do this in app.component??

Comment: Cause panel bar is main thing and I want to change panel bar after route will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I make something like this in constructor and it works.

```
router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.subsRouteResult = (event.url).substring(1);
    this.changeRoute();
 }
})
```

I have action in changeRoute method.